# Guice Request Scope for tracing workflow of request

Tags: java, guice, requestscope

I have a use case where I have 6 steps being performed in one request. The business is requesting that we capture metrics on what the result of each step was in the process. They want us to log to a Kinesis stream.

Architecturally I am looking at the best solution. We have java based services I want to have a request scoped object enriched as the request progresses, then when the endpoint finishes we would make a service call to kinesis asynchronous using a fire and forget pattern. This way the reporting is not holding up the main thread.

I was looking at using the raw ThreadLocal or guice scope. Has anyone ran into to a similar problem that they solved? Im thinking of use guice request scoped components, which will greatly simply the code. Just looking for some opinions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you aren't on a servlet environment because, then, you will just use the built in request scope. Even then you can use the request scope from *guice-servlet* building the scope yourself.

```
void processRequest() {
    RequestScoper scope = ServletScopes.scopeRequest(Collections.emptyMap());
    try ( RequestScoper.CloseableScope ignored = scope.open() ) {
        step1();
        step2();
        step3();
        step4();
        step5();
        step6();
    }
}
```

You can use `@RequestScoped` and it will be the same object on all your steps. You can, for example, use a provider to get access to it.